# Maximizing two codependant profit equations for Bertrand Model Oligopolies

Tags: calculus, economics

For this problem I was given the Fixed Cost, Marginal cost, and demand curves for two firms (x and y). So far, from this information I derived the profit (π) function for each firm.

π(x)=-0.01x^2+70x+0.005xy-10y-120000

π(y)=-0.01y^2+520y+0.005xy-10x-1020000

Normally, when maximizing profit, we would use LaGrange. However, the λ constraint was something like cost or budget.

My second guess is to simply take the first partial derivative of each to maximize, but I dont think that will account for the fact that each profit function is dependent on outcome of the other.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

(apologies for format)

Comment: So It looks like my 2nd guess was correct. Taking the partial of each maintains the dependent variables.